# Transition of firefox addon from bootstrapped to webextension not working

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to make a transition from a bootstrapped addon to a webextension addon. To this end, I wanted to start with an intermediate version that is a bootstrapped extension with embedded webextension; this should in particular copy the personal settings from old-style preferences to new-style local storage.

I think I followed the instructions I found:

- I added the embedded webestension as `webextension\manifest.json` and `webextension\background.js`
- I added `<em:hasEmbeddedWebExtension>true</em:hasEmbeddedWebExtension>` to install.rdf
- I invoke `webextension.startup` from within `startup()` in bootstrap.js; this would then cause the copying of the settings via some messages

From what I rad in the docs, the first parameter of `startup(data,reason)` is supposed to be augmented by a `webextension` property. However, it seems that this is not the case: my dump shows only `id`, `version`, `installPath`, `resourceURI`, and `instanceID`, hence I cannot do the third point above.
What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Stripped down to a minimal example, `minimal.xpi`, containing

- `bootstrap.js` (note the signature of `startup` following the webextension examples instead of the "old-style" `startup(data,reason)`)

  ```
  function startup({webextension} /*was: data,reason*/) {
    console.log("A");
    webextension.startup().then(api => {
      console.log("B");
    });
    console.log("C");
  }
  ```
- `install.rdf`

  ```
  <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
     <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
       <em:id>minimalexample@example</em:id>
       <em:name>Minimal Example</em:name>
       <em:version>1.0.0</em:version>
       <em:type>2</em:type>
       <em:hasEmbeddedWebExtension>true</em:hasEmbeddedWebExtension>
       <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>    
        <!-- Firefox -->
       <em:targetApplication>
         <Description>
           <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
           <em:minVersion>46.0</em:minVersion>
           <em:maxVersion>99.0</em:maxVersion>
         </Description>
       </em:targetApplication>
     </Description>
  </RDF>
  ```
- `webextension\manifest.json`

  ```
  {
  "name": "minimal example embedded webextension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2
  }
  ```

**Expected behaviour:** "A", "B" and "C" appear in the console log (where "B" *may* appear after "C" due to the asynchronous nature of the promise)

**Actual behaviour:** "A" appears in the log, but followed by

```
addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on
 minimalexample@example: TypeError: webextension is undefined
 (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> 
 jar:file:///home/obscured/minimal.xpi!/bootstrap.js:4:5) 
 JS Stack trace: startup@bootstrap.js:4:5 <
 this.XPIProvider.callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4800:9 <
 this.XPIProvider.installTemporaryAddon<@XPIProvider.jsm:3993:5
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser console (ctrl-shift-J)?  You might also try running this example https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/embedded-webextension-bootstrapped and comparing it with your own code.

Comment: I might have found my facepalm-inducing error: While *webextensions* have been around for quite a while (FF 45), the desired method to make a smooth transition from bootstrapped to webextension via *embedded* webextensions exists only from FF 51 -- and I was developing with my default installation FF 50. Can anybody confirm that this is my problem? Intriguingly, I *did* update the `<em:minmalVersion>` field to 51.0 in my real addon, but it would still be loaded via about:debugging without complaints - hence I didn't bother to check my current browser version ...

Comment: Yep that's it, embeded is only support in FF51+. Here are some simple examples - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311508 - see the attached embed.xpi and timer loop.xpi

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, If you have found a solution, you should post an answer. Self-answered questions are encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, there is no real problem, or at least there would not have been in a non-debugging environment:

First of all, ot should be noted that *webextensions* have been around since FireFox version 45. However, until recently it has been difficult to transition from a legacy addon to a webextension addon. Namely, transitional addons that are legacy addons with *embedded* webextensions are available only from version 51 of FireFox.
Consequently, when writing an addon with embedded webextensions, one should be careful to have at least `<em:minimalVersion>51.0</em:minimalVersion>` in the install.rdf of the transitional addon.
Being the careful programmer I am, I indeed had this setting in my addon (and was happy that this prevented premature updates for people running older FireFox versions, as expected).

So on I went with debugging my transitional addon (using `firefox --console` and `about:debugging` to load the unsigned test versions) and observed what I wrote in the question post.
The explanation for the problems I observed was simply that I did the debuggung with my normal stable FireFox (at that time version 50) and didn't notice that because no error occured when attempting to load the addon (and an error would occur with a version below `<em:minimalVersion>`, wouldn't it). But of course(?) that is already a feature of debugging: In that mode, addons are loaded even if the version check fails ...

With a newer FireFox (aurora or nightly), all was fine.